# RadViz & survey/permutation matrix plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm currently working on a brief presentation for a graduate class in multivariate data analysis. It's on methods of displaying multivariate data (for human comprehension), and of the six methods we're supposed to present on, I've taken on [radial visualization plots](http://www.agocg.ac.uk/reports/visual/casestud/brunsdon/radviz.htm) (specifically the type referred to as "RadViz") and survey plots (which are a variety of permutation matrix visualization, or so I've been led to understand from my research). While I have been able to find sufficient resources on the uses of these visualization methods, as well as their benefits/drawbacks, I'm coming up with problems finding code to implement them in R.

I have located two user-written functions that will do [survey plots](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~maitra/stat501/Rcode/surveyplot.R) and [radial visualization](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~maitra/stat501/Rcode/radviz2d.R) in R. These appear to part of the package "dprep", which has since been discontinued from CRAN--and try as I might, I cannot seem to get it to install as a package when I download the older version from the archive. Additionally, all of this code is now six years and several versions out of data, and I am hesitant to recommend it to classmates if it may become completely unusable at some point.

I suppose what I'm asking is if there is any easier or cleaner way--possibly as part of an existing package--to implement these visualizations in R, or if my only option is using the above (very old) code to do it. I'm aware of solutions in other programming languages (Python) as well as other pieces of software (Orange, VisuLab), but since the class is primarily based around using R, I'd like to be able to present in it if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like we need to teach you to search. The google pathway is always available but for R functionality it sometimes is not sufficiently specific if the topic name is commonly used for other concepts. I often pair the search term with 'rproject'

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=radviz&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=radviz+rproject
```

Brings up:

```
http://www.cs.uml.edu/~phoffman/Radviz/readme.txt # R interface to C-implementation
```

... as well as many others but it would take some effort to sort through to find R-specific implementation.

I have many successes using the `findFn`-function in the sos package:

```
install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
```

Originally I thought this was just the ordinary radar chart but seems it might be something different.

```
> findFn("Radial Coordinate Visualization")
found 12 matches;  retrieving 1 page

Downloaded 4 links in 3 packages.
```

The search on Radviz only brings up a single item, `radviz2d`, whose help page links to a `surveyplot` function in the same package 'dprep'. The term 'radial' alone brought up a large number, possibly unmanageable:

```
> findFn("radial plots")
found 456 matches;  retrieving 20 pages, 400 matches.
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Those terms deliver a somewhat more manageable number. Radar plots or spider plots are generally being used for discrete variables, but radial coordinate visualization appears to be a method of projecting multivariate associations on a two-dimensional domain.  The 'circular' package also deals with display and statistics on continuous variables.

From the CRAN Archive I downloaded and unpackaed version 2.1 of radviz: `dprep_2.1.tar.gz`:

```
source('~/Downloads/dprep/R/radviz2d.R', chdir = TRUE)
  mmnorm <-
 function (data,minval=0,maxval=1) 
 {
 d=dim(data)
 c=class(data)
 cnames=colnames(data)
 classes=data[,d[2]]
 data=data[,-d[2]]
 minvect=apply(data,2,min)
 maxvect=apply(data,2,max)
 rangevect=maxvect-minvect
 zdata=scale(data,center=minvect,scale=rangevect)
 newminvect=rep(minval,d[2]-1)
 newmaxvect=rep(maxval,d[2]-1)
 newrangevect=newmaxvect-newminvect
 zdata2=scale(zdata,center=FALSE,scale=(1/newrangevect))
 zdata3=zdata2+newminvect
 zdata3=cbind(zdata3,classes)
 if (c=="data.frame") zdata3=as.data.frame(zdata3)
 colnames(zdata3)=cnames
 return(zdata3)
 }
load("/Users/davidwinsemius/Downloads/dprep/data/my.iris.rda")
radviz2d(my.iris,"Iris")
```

[image]

The package also has several other functions including survey plot that are available in R, so they do not need to be compile. There is a compiled function in the package which I have not investigated.

Comment: I actually found all of this myself, which is why I tried to summarize it in the original question. (I am sorry I didn't do a very good job of it--it was late at night and there was rather a lot of stuff I was trying to summarize without the question going on forever.) RadViz is as you say, a method for projecting high-dimensional data sets down into two dimensions, and it's distinct from other forms of radial charts. [This](http://www.agocg.ac.uk/reports/visual/casestud/brunsdon/radviz.htm) is a good summary of the technique.

Comment: Sifting through 'radviz rproject' on Google yielded only the deprecated "dprep" package you found, as I mentioned in the original question. I wanted to know if there were other options available, and I guess I didn't make that totally clear, for which I apologize.

Comment: I was able to load the `.r` code from the dprep-package and run it. I wouldn't call it "deprecated", only abandoned.

Comment: Ah, fair. Maybe "discontinued" is the better term, since it's no longer part of the archive. I'm having trouble installing the code but can continue to work on it. So I suppose the answer is there is no other R-specific implementation of either of these except what's in dprep?

Comment: I hesitate about being categorical about no other solution other than the two I offered.

Comment: Unfortunately my searches have found nothing other than dprep that would do it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have released a new version of dprep. Edgar Acuna